# Mismatch between client-side data and server-side data after changing tabs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am working on a web app similar to google docs; each page has three documents tabs which are dynamically rendered. Think of three documents in a single page that you can access via clicking different tabs.

```
const Draft = () => {
  const [draftData, setDraftData] = useState<Document>(defaultDraftData);
  const [activePage, setActivePage] = useState<
    'One' | 'Two' | 'Three'
  >('One');

  const contents = {
    One: {
      Content: ContentOne,
      props: {},
    },
    Two: {
      Content: ContentTwo,
      props: {},
    },
    Three: {
      Content: ContentThree,
      props: {},
    },
  };

  const { Content, props } = contents[activePage];

  useEffect(() => {
      axios.get(apiRoute)
        .then(function (response) {
          setDraftData(response.data);
        });
    }
  }, []);

  return (
      <div className="bg-offwhite flex flex-col">
        <SideBar activePage={activePage} setActivePage={setActivePage} />
        <LayoutApp>
          <Header header={title} draftId={draftId} />
          <Content {...props} />
        </LayoutApp>
        <UtilBar />
      </div>
  );
};
```

So in short:

- this page loads `draftData` which includes content for all three document tabs
- in each ContentOne, ContentTwo, etc: uses react-save to auto-save any changes and uses useState to keep track of its contents
- component is responsible for changing the tab

And I am having the mismatch problem of client-side data and server-side data. Making changes on one tab will change the useState then make a PATCH request so changes are reflected to the server-side data.

However, changing to another tab and going back will not render the changes as it was stored in useState, while changes can be seen when the entire page reloads.

The easiest solution is to make a separate FETCH call every time user changes the document tab, but I think there’s a better way to do this. I would appreciate any thoughts you guys have!

Answer (score 0):

While I do see some ways you can play with `useState` and even `useContext` to handle the states of the tabs, I believe making a `fetch` for every tab change is the cleaner solution, because it seems more logical.

You have the `useEffect` already, so you can simply add `activePage` to the dependencies array.

Another solution (perhaps a next step from what I mentioned above) is to use [React Query](https://react-query.tanstack.com/), if it's possible to use external libraries. I'm sorry I can't dive deep on how you would implement that, so I'm just throwing this idea here and hope it helps!